# Windows Service or WCF Serice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I need to implement simple file watcher utility. I have decided to implement this in a simple windows service which will internally use FileSystemWatcher. The purpose is to monitor given directory path (or ftp) and copy the file to some other server wherever new file comes in after checking some predefined logic

As I am using .net 3.5; client suggested me to use WCF. I have very less experience in WCF.

I am not sure how I can create WCF service which will function like WindowsService and can be deployed in services on windows server.

To be a futuristic is it a good idea to create WCF service instead of  windows service, or I should insist on window service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Service != WCF**

You can't create a WCF service that acts functions like a windows service. A WCF service waits for messages from third parties and acts on them, a windows service is a process that is always running in the background. WCF tries to solve the problem of separating out the communication mechanism (transport protocols such as Tcp, Http, Named Pipe, etc) from the service interfaces.

**File Watcher Utility**

While in theory it's possible to create a new Flat-File binding in WCF that "could" have it's address set to a file system location, one does not exist directly in the .NET framework. Looking at the [Custom Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx) article on MSDN it's not immediately obvious to me how one would construct a File System binding. These are the defined transport options available:

1. TCP
2. HTTP
3. HTTPS
4. Named Pipes (IPC)
5. Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
6. Message Queueing (MSMQ)
7. Custom

If communication must be done through file drops, then WCF does not solve your problem.

**Where WCF Might Work**

What the client might have meant is to create a WCF endpoint that does the `copy the file to some other server wherever new file comes in after checking some predefined logic`, but you would still want to have a windows service with a `FileWatcher` monitoring the input directory.

If you have multiple clients that need to be able to perform that same logic and then send the output to that other server then it might make sense to make the WCF service, otherwise it's over-engineered at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the simplest option until you find a need to change, with the simplest option being a Windows Service.

There is a coding principle call YAGNI (you ain't gonna need it) that applies in this case as simply wrapping something up in a WCF service would do nothing but add unneeded complexity for the majority of cases. Simply put do the minimum viable solution and extend only when you need to.

PS. If you are using the FileSystemWatcher over network shares note that there are documented problems with it and you should use a combination of a poll + FileSystemWatcher. There are lots of explanations on Stack Overflow about it.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, the Windows Service makes a lot more sense and I think that to be the more appropriate solution. You need something that is always running and monitoring a directory and thats exactly the use case which Windows services are very good at.

I would consider talking to the client and explaining the Windows Services are the more appropriate solution to this kind of use case. Also, windows services are not old hat, they are there to solve exactly these kinds of use cases and WCF / windows services complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

Both features have **Service** in their names by they have virtually nothing in common.

A Windows service runs constantly on a single machine.

A WCF service is code than can be called remotely by other machines.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on what you need to do. A Windows Service and a "WCF service" have little in common.

The question here is whether you need a HTTP endpoint or not. If you do, you could even host a WCF service in your windows service to provide that. Keep in mind that a WCF is only used as a way to communicate between applications.

Reading your description, though, it doesn't seem like you need it.

[WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)